# How to check if an app is installed from a JS in Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari

I want to create text on page depend on is my app installed or not.
I already implemented a custom url scheme in app for example:

```
myapp://
```

but don't know how to check from JS is my app installed or not.
**Note**: I don't want to run app, just only check.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to detect the app is installed without redirecting to app from javascript.

Below code will redirect to the app if installed else callback is called.

```
setTimeout(function () { 
          //callback if the app is not installed.
}, 25);
window.location = "myapp://somethingyouwanttosend";
```

You can also take a look at [smart banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) it might solve your problem.

Comment: but how Safari figure out can it open url or not?

Comment: If you trying to just detect if the app is installed without redirecting to app than it is not possible. However you can detect the app is not installed. If it is installed than it will redirect to the app.